# How to check if a column exists in a pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multi-index, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex of columns like this:

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0] * 8], columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['a', 'b'], [1, 2], [2000, 2001]])
)

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
     a                   b
     1         2         1         2
  2000 2001 2000 2001 2000 2001 2000 2001
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

In [46]: df.columns.levels
Out[46]: FrozenList([[u'a', u'b'], [1, 2], [2000, 2001]])
```

I need to know, for all values of level 0 and some specific value of level 1, what are all the existing unique values of level 2 (say the DataFrame goes through some process in which for some values of level 1 and level 0, level 2 is dropped). The best I've been able to come up with so far is this:

```
In [54]: level_1_val = 2

In [55]: cols_series = df.columns.to_series()

In [56]: cols_series[
   ....:     cols_series.index.get_level_values(1) == level_1_val
   ....: ].index.get_level_values(2).unique()

array([2000, 2001])
```

What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.xs(2, axis=1, level=1).groupby(axis=1, level=1).first().columns.values

array([2000, 2001])
```

Or

```
df.xs(2, axis=1, level=1).columns.get_level_values(level=1).unique()
```